# Specifying Big-O notation in java (algorithms)

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o, computer-science

I am struggling in fully understanding big-o notation, and would appreciate some guidance with the following questions in the image provided.
I have an answer of O(n^2) for the first question, however i am not fully confident in my answer. Any help would be great thanks.

[image]

Comment: Question 1 is O(n). Question is O(n²). What problems do you have with that?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose The first one isn't O(n). It has `count = count * 5` for its update.

Comment: @khelwood What else? The 5 is a constant which does not count towards O notation. `O(n/5) == O(n)`!

Comment: If you increase n by a factor of 5, you get one extra iteration. That's not linear.

Comment: @khelwood. Ah, there the mistake. It is `count` that is increased, not `n`! So it is still O(n).

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose You misunderstand my point. Doing the whole loop with `n=5000` does one more iteration than doing the whole loop with `n=1000`. That's nowhere near O(n).

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose lets say n=300, the loop will then run for count=1,25,125, so only 3 times.

Comment: @khelwood How you will express first algorithm in terms of big-o? I understand that its not exactly linear but in big-o terms, as far as i know, it will be expressed as O(N).

Comment: I think it's O(log n).

Comment: @khelwood Constants can completely be ignored in O notation. As I said `O(5000) == O(1000) == O(1)` (which would be a constant time). `O(n/x) == O(n * y) == O(n + z) == O(n)` (which is linear) for any x,y,z!

Comment: Actually, since the O notation gives only a kind of upper bound O(log n) and O(n) are both correct. But O(log n) is the much tighter bound.

Comment: Ah. My mistake. I understand now! Seems indeed more to be O(log n).

Comment: @Yousaf If you multply n by some constant factor (in this case 5) the number of steps goes up by some constant amount (in this case 1). That's O(log n).

Comment: @Henry I just did some calculation and i think you are right on point. O(log n) also makes sense.

Comment: @khelwood yes you are right, just did some calculation and O(log N) makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

In the first question the complexity is O(log<sub>5</sub>N), that is, it is `O(log N)`, as the number of iterations is limited by a condition `5^N`.  Aside comment, in the first question a `product` is calculated, not a `sum`.

In the second question the number of iterations is `(N - 5) * (2 * N) * 1000`, which is roughly equal to `2000 * N^2`, so big-O is `O(N^2)`.